# How to dynamically Generate Sort strings for Data Layer from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help refactoring this code to dynamically generate a sort string that I can send to my data layer so that my database does the sorting instead of it happening in memory. I am using MVC4 with EF5 as my data layer.

```
public ActionResult InstanceSearch(int? page, string sortOrder, string computerName, string instanceName,
                                       string productName, string version)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;

        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        if (pageNumber < 1)
        {
            pageNumber = 1;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder))
        {
            sortOrder = "Computer";
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.ComputerSort = sortOrder == "Computer" ? "ComputerDesc" : "Computer";
        ViewBag.InstanceSort = sortOrder == "Instance" ? "InstanceDesc" : "Instance";
        ViewBag.VersionSort = sortOrder == "Version" ? "VersionDesc" : "Version";
        ViewBag.ProductSort = sortOrder == "Product" ? "ProductDesc" : "Product";

        //IEnumerable<Instance> instances = ecuWebDataContext.Instances;

        IQueryable<Instance> instances
        = string.IsNullOrEmpty(computerName) == true ? ecuWebDataContext.Instances : ecuWebDataContext.Instances.Where(i => i.Computer.Name == computerName);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceName) == false)
        {
            instances = instances.Where(i => i.Name == instanceName);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
        {
            ProductName product = (ProductName)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProductName), productName);
            instances = instances.Where(i => i.Product.Name == product);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
        {
            instances = instances.Where(i => i.Version == version);
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Computer":
                instances = instances.OrderBy(i => i.Computer.Name);
                break;

            case "ComputerDesc":
                instances = instances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Computer.Name);
                break;

            case "Instance":
                instances = instances.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
                break;

            case "InstanceDesc":
                instances = instances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Name);
                break;

            case "Version":
                instances = instances.OrderBy(i => i.Version);
                break;

            case "VersionDesc":
                instances = instances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Version);
                break;

            case "Product":
                instances = instances.OrderBy(i => i.Product.Name);
                //instances = instances.OrderBy(i => Enum.Parse(typeof(ProductName), i.Product.Name));
                break;

            case "ProductDesc":
                instances = instances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Product.Name);
                //instances = instances.OrderByDescending(i => Enum.Parse(typeof(ProductName), i.Product.Name));
                break;
        }
        ViewBag.SortOrder = sortOrder;

        var instanceSearchModel = new InstanceSearchModel { ComputerName = computerName, InstanceName = instanceName };
        ViewBag.ComputerName = computerName;
        ViewBag.InstanceName = instanceName;
        ViewBag.ProductName = productName;
        ViewBag.InstanceCount = instances.Count();
        ViewBag.Version = version;
        return View(instances.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I tried returning an IQueryable from the data layer, but then I run into connection problems because I never close it.

Comment: Does this work correctly? If not, then you need to get it working before posting here.

Comment: Yes this works correctly. However I have wrappers around the datalayer to hide it behind interfaces so I can swap out databases without affecting the application and this code uses the database context directly which has the intened effect of offloading to the database for the sorting, but I am looking for help building the sort string then sending it completely to my data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data layer that appears to be causing your problem is the root cause.

You're abstracting over an abstraction, and in the process having to marshall sort orders around as a result. Prefer injecting your context in a request scope and remove the abstraction.

You can always create an abstraction over the specific query, and inject the query, which has a dependency on the context, if you *really* need to.

Comment: Ok thank you i will get started on doing that.